# Django Rest Framework: upload image to a particular existing model's object

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Hey I am trying to upload an image using Rest API[via Postman] to an object which already exists, and has all its field populated except for the image. I am using PUT method, to first get the object I want to upload the image to then trying to pass it through the serializer. The images are to be uploaded to my S3 bucket.
The code for my views.py:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def putproof(request):
    app=MasterTaskHolder.objects.filter(title=request.data['title'],user=request.user)
    serializer=ImageUploadSerializer(app,data=request.data,partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response("Posted")
```

My serializer:

```
class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MasterTaskHolder
        fields = (
            'title','image'
        )
```

My model:

```
class MasterTaskHolder(models.Model):
    status_code = [
        ('C', 'Completed'),
        ('P', 'Pending'),
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_code, default='P')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="imageproof/")

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.user} - '+(f'{self.title}'))
```

I am really new to Django and DRF, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this?

```py
class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MasterTaskHolder
        fields = (
            'title','image'
        )

    def update(self, instance: MasterTaskHolder, validated_data):
        instance.image = validated_data['image']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

In views instead of using `serializer.save()` use the overrided update that we just create

`serializer.update(instance, serializer.validated_data)`

Also you are sending a **queryset** to serializer you need to change that to the object itself and humble suggestion don't forget to validate if that object exist or not.